# jQuery Mobile: Adding Admob to page created by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, admob

Basically I am trying to add the javascript code for the admob advert into each of the footers on each of the pages created by jQuery mobile. As I am trying to make a native app, I can't use php(to my knowledge).

For each item of news in the xml feed, I create a new page using jquery. I basically insert the code into the page's footer like this:

```
page += '<div data-role="footer" data-theme="c" data-position="fixed"><script type="text/javascript">var admob_vars = { pubid: "************",  bgcolor: "01acca", text: "fff", test: true };</script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://mmv.admob.com/static/iphone/iadmob.js"></script></div>';
```

However when i view the working code, the footer appears and is added just fine, but the admob script seems to have disappeared. Am i doing this all completely wrong? Or have i made a simple mistake somewhere?

Comment: Do you have a live web page somewhere where we can inspect the page to see what's happening?

Comment: http://wiiuandmii.com/ch02/app (obviously you won't be able to see the working ad from a normal web browser, but you will see the lack of code in the #news1 page for example after it gets created) You'll probably notice a whole lot of other issues i am having ;_;

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues using jquery mobile and loading external Javascript files because the requests are made via AJAX and a lot of tags are stripped out.

Instead trying loading the script like this:

```
var fileref=document.createElement('script');
fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
fileref.setAttribute("src", "http://mmv.admob.com/static/iphone/iadmob.js");
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);

page += '<div data-role="footer" data-theme="c" data-position="fixed"><script type="text/javascript">var admob_vars = { pubid: "************",  bgcolor: "01acca", text: "fff", test: true };</script></div>';
```

Also make sure all of your pages are wrapped in a div tag with the data-role="page" because only content within their gets loaded.